# For what values of $k \in \mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$ does there exist an unbiased estimator of $e^{k \lambda}$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, parameter-estimation

This is inspired by [Finding an unbiased estimator of $e^{-2\lambda}$ for Poisson distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2689276/finding-an-unbiased-estimator-of-e-2-lambda-for-poisson-distribution/), reminding me of a qualifying exam question that I was frustrated with.

Suppose $X_1, \dots, X_n \overset{\text{iid}}{\sim}\text{Poisson}(\lambda)$.

For some subset of size $k \leq n$, it can be seen that if $\mathbf{I}$ is the indicator function that
$$\mathbf{I}(X_{i_1}+X_{i_2}+\cdots+X_{i_k}=0)$$
is an unbiased estimator of $e^{-k\lambda}$ for $k \geq 1$.

The OP of the linked question above asked an interesting question: does there exist an unbiased estimator of $e^{2\lambda}$? More generally,

> Is there an unbiased estimator of $e^{k\lambda}$ for $k > 0$?

In the comments to the link above, I told the OP I wouldn't know where to begin with this. My first thought was to try finding the distribution of the reciprocal of a Poisson distribution. Say $X \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda)$, then
$$f_{1/X}(y)=\dfrac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{1/y}}{(1/y)!}$$
(what is even the support of this thing?)
and I suppose $(1/y)!$ would have to be extended in cases where $1/y$ isn't an integer... so basically, every case except $y = 1$, and then we'd have to use the Gamma function. But even with this, using indicator functions (as above) will still give $e^{-k \lambda}$ for $k \geq 1$; it doesn't help the problem much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some unbiased estimators of $e^{a\lambda}$, for every nonnegative $a$, based on any i.i.d. sample $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ of Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$:

- Using $X_1$ only, $$(1+a)^{X_1}$$
- Using $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$, $$\left(1+\frac an\right)^{X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n}$$
- If asymmetry is allowed, $$\prod_{i=1}^na_i^{X_i}$$ for every real numbers $(a_i)$ such that $$\sum_{i=1}^na_i=n+a$$

And so on.

Comment: In this context, a slightly amazing, unbiased, estimator of $e^{-2\lambda}$, with values in $\{+1,-1\}$ only, should be at least mentioned: $$(-1)^{Y_1}$$

Comment: How did you derive this (or figure it out)?

Comment: @Mr.BromwichI Folklore and/or case $a=-2$ of the first estimator in the answer.

Comment: Oh I meant how you derived the unbiased estimators for $e^{a\lambda}$.

Comment: @Mr.BromwichI From the well known form of the [Poisson generating function](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Probability_Generating_Function_of_Poisson_Distribution).