# Find the UMVUE for $Pr[X=0]=e^{-\lambda}$

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, parameter-estimation

I am working on a problem that requires me to find the UMVUE of $Pr[X=0]=e^{-\lambda}$.

There are several issues that I am having so I would really appreciate your help.

1), What does it mean to be an "estimator" of a probability?
I understand that estimators can estimate parameters such as the mean or variance of a distribution, but I do not quite get the intuitive meaning of this problem. . .

2), The notes that I am looking at mentions

$$\Bbb{I}_{\{X_1=0\}}$$

is a "natural choice" of an unbiased estimator of $Pr[X=0]$.

I am thinking that because I don't understand intuitively what is going on I am not seeing why an indicator is an estimator.

The notes further proceeds to simplifying

$$E[\Bbb{I}_{\{X_1=0\}}|\sum_{i=1}^n X_i=x]$$

which leads to

$$\left( \frac{n-1}{n} \right)^x$$

I understand the rest of the algebraic portion, but because I don't know why it started off like this it does not stay in my head.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Because $E\left[\mathbb I_{\{X_1=0\}}\right]=P(X_1=0)=e^{-\lambda}$. The probability is a function of $\lambda$ which is unknown, so you are estimating it.

Comment: So, let me make sure that I understand this.  $\Bbb{I}_{X_1=0}=1$ when $X_1=0$ and $=0$ when $X_1\ne 0$ so under that condition $E[\Bbb{I}_{X_1=0}]=\sum_{X}\Bbb{I}_{X_1=0}*Pr[X=x]$.  So, if $X_1=0$ then $\because = 1*Pr[X_1=0]$ and when $X_1 \ne 0$ then $\because = 0*Pr[X_1 \ne 0]$

Comment: I see that numerically it is true.  However, why would it be "natural" to think that this is the estimator?  I mean, this means that the probability is either 1 or 0 right?  I do not find that to be natural at all. . .

Comment: Not numerically, it is exactly true. To repeat, perhaps the most trivial unbiased estimator of a parametric function like the probability $P(X\in A)$ is the indicator of the event $X\in A$, since $E(I_{X\in A})=1.P(X\in A)+0.P(X\notin A)$.

Comment: Hmm... I will just accept the algebraic part and hope that I spend enough time in stats that someday I understand.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2689415/321264