# Unbiased estimator for a parameter in a Poisson distribution

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

Suppose that $X_1,X_2,\ldots , X_n$ for a random sample from a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$.
Propose an unbiased estimator for $\theta = e^{-\lambda}$

My attempt was to substitute this estimator in the Poisson distribution $f(x|\lambda)$ = $\frac{\lambda^{x} e^{-\lambda}}{x!}$ obtaining $\frac{\log(\theta^{x}) \theta}{x!}$.
I don't know if this is the right approach and I wouldn't know how to find an unbiased estimator afterwards.
I thought about calculating the MLE of this new distribution, but I don't know if it was correct.

Any help/hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Similar problems at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2689415/321264 and its linked posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $P(X_n = 0) = e^{-\lambda}$. This motivates the following estimator. Set $Y_n = 1(X_n = 0)$, so that $Y_n \sim \mathrm{Bern}(e^{- \lambda})$ and $\mathbb{E}(Y_n) = P(X_n = 0) = e^{-\lambda}$. The estimator $$\overline{Y}_n = \frac{1}{n}(Y_1 + \ldots + Y_n) = \frac{1}{n} (1(X_1 = 0) + \ldots + 1(X_n = 0))$$
is then an unbiased estimator for $\theta = e^{- \lambda}$.

Comment: $1(X_1 = 0)$ and $1(X_n = 0)$ etc. are also unbiased estimators, and yours is the average of these so also unbiased