# Confusion in finding conditional expecation of indicator function (Lehmann-Scheffe)

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

I'm trying to find the UMVUE of $e^{-2\lambda}$ with
$X_1, X_2,\ldots,X_n \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$ being independent.

So since $T(X) := \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ is a complete sufficient statistic for the Poisson distribution, and also $W(X):= \mathbf{I}(X_1 + X_2 = 0)$ is an unbiased estimator of $e^{-2\lambda}$, then by Lehmann_Scheffe,
$$\tau(T)= \mathbb{E}(W(T)\mid T(X))
$$
is the UMVUE of $e^{-2\lambda}$.

I'm having trouble computing $\tau$ so I would like to see if this is correct:
First, to find the expectation, I need the PDF.
$$\mathbb{P}(W(T)=s\mid T(X)=t) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(W(T)=s \ \cap \ T(X) = t)}{\mathbb{P}(T(X) = t)} \\ = \frac{\mathbb{P}(\mathbf{I}(X_1 + X_2 = 0)  = s \ \cap \ X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_2 = t)}{\mathbb{P}(X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n = t)}\\ = \frac{\mathbb{P}(\mathbf{I}(X_3 + X_4 + \cdots + X_n = t)=s)}{\mathbb{P}(X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n = t)}  
$$
The denominator is just $\frac{e^{-n\lambda}(n\lambda)^t}{t!}$.
When $s=1$, we have 
$$\mathbb{P}(\mathrm{I}(X_3+X_4+\cdots+X_n=t) =1) = \frac{e^{-(n-2)\lambda}((n-2)\lambda)^t}{t!}  
$$
So 
$$\mathbb{P}(\mathrm{I}(X_3+X_4+\cdots+X_n=t) =0) = 1 - \frac{e^{-(n-2)\lambda}((n-2)\lambda)^t}{t!}  
$$
After this, I'm unsure of how to find the expectation. Is my approach correct?

Comment: "to find the expectation, I need the PDF" No, you do not need the PDF.

Comment: When do you not need the PDF? (Is it when you can apply the law of iterated expectation)?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2689276/finding-an-unbiased-estimator-of-e-2-lambda-for-poisson-distribution?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\e}{\operatorname{E}}$
You need $\e(W \mid X_1+\cdots+X_n).$

To find that, first find $\e(W\mid X_1+\cdots+X_n = x)$ as a function of $x,$ as follows:
\begin{align}
& \e(W \mid X_1+\cdots+X_n = x) = \Pr(W=1\mid X_1+\cdots+X_n=x) \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{\Pr(W=1\ \&\ X_1+\cdots+X_n=x)}{\Pr(X_1+\cdots+X_n=x)} \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{\Pr(X_1=X_2=0)\Pr(X_3+\cdots+X_n=x)}{\Pr(X_1+\cdots+X_n=x)}
\end{align}
That last equality holds because the event $[W=1\ \&\ X_1+\cdots +X_n=x]$ is the same as the event $[X_1=X_2=0\ \&\ X_3+\cdots+X_n=x],$ and the event depending on $X_1,X_2$ is independent of the event depending on $X_3,\ldots,X_n.$

Then just apply the probability mass function for the Poisson distribution and then do a lot of simplification. That gets you a function of $x.$ That function evaluated at $X_1+\cdots+X_n$ will be the UMVUE.

Note that for a number of simple reasons, one must expect all occurrences of $\lambda$ to cancel out. If that does not happen, then something is wrong.

Comment: What are some reasons why all occurrences of $\lambda$ should cancel out? And also in the last equality (and the paragrpah following), do you mean $X_1 + X_2 = 0$?

Comment: @Mr.BromwichI : Since both $X_1$ and $X_2$ take values only in the set $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\},$ the event $X_1+X_2=0$ is the same as $X_1=X_1=0.$ The reason $\lambda$ should cancel out is seen in the definition of sufficiency. To say that $X_1+\cdots+X_n$ is sufficient for this family of distributions means that the conditional distribution of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ given $X_1+\cdots+X_n$ does not depend on $\lambda;$ consequently neither does the distribution of any function of that sum, so $\lambda$ should cancel out. And you can't use something that depends on $\lambda$ as an estimator.

Comment: Hi again, sorry for a late question. In your  last equality, why is there a product of $Pr(X_1=X_2=0)$? Shouldn't it have been "absorbed" when you took the intersection in the previous equality?  
$$Pr(W = 1 \cap X_1 + \ldots + X_n = x) \Rightarrow Pr(X_1 = X_2 = 0 \cap X_3 + \ldots + X_n = x) \Rightarrow Pr(X_3 + \ldots + X_n = x)$$?

Comment: @Mr.BromwichI : The following events are all the same: $$ \begin{align} & \big[ W=1\ \&\ X_1+\cdots+X_n =x\big] \\ \\ & \big[ W=1\ \&\ X_3+\cdots+ X_n = x \big] \\  \\ & \big[ X_1=X_2=0\ \&\ X_3+\cdots+X_n=x\big] \end{align} $$ The following is NOT the same event: $$ \big[ X_3+\cdots+X_n=x \big] $$ because that event can happen even if $X_1\ne0$ or $X_2\ne0. \qquad$

Answer (score 3):

Just cancel out the joint terms, i.e., 
$$
\varrho(X) = \mathbb{E}[W(X)\mid T=s]=\frac{\mathbb{P}(X_1 + X_2 = 0)\mathbb{P}(\sum_{i=3}^n X_i = s)}{\mathbb{P}(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i  = s)} \\= \frac{e^{-2\lambda} e^{-(n-2)\lambda} (n-2)^s \lambda^s/s!}{ e^{-n\lambda} n^s \lambda^s/s! },
$$
with some canceling and rearrangement you have
$$
\varrho(X) = \left( \left( 1 - \frac{2}{n} \right)^n \right)^{\bar{X}_n}.
$$
To be sure you can use the continuous mapping theorem and the WLLN to note that as $(1-2/n)^n \to e^{-2}$ and $\bar{X}_n \xrightarrow{P} \lambda $, $\varrho(X) \xrightarrow{P} e^{-2\lambda}$.

And for the expectation use the fact that $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \sim \mathcal{P}oiss(n\lambda)$, hence
$$
\mathbb{E}\varrho(X) = e^{-\lambda n}\sum_{s=0}^{\infty}\left( \lambda n( 1-  2/n\right))^s/s!=e^{-\lambda n + \lambda n - 2\lambda} = e^{-2\lambda}.
$$

Comment: +1. Note $\left( \left( 1 - \frac{2}{n} \right)^n \right)^{\bar{X}_n} = \left( 1 - \frac{2}{n} \right)^{\sum X_i}$