# MVU estimator for $e^{-\lambda}$ for a given Poisson Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Give, $Y_1, Y_2, ... Y_n$ are IID random variables, each having a Poisson Distribution with parameter $\lambda$. Is there any unbiased estimator of either (i) $e^{-\lambda}$ or (ii) $e^{-2\lambda}$ whose variance can achieve the Cramer- Rao bound corresponding to them? 
For $e^{-\lambda}$ , I found the CRLB to be $\dfrac{\lambda}{n}e^{-2\lambda}$ 
and for $e^{-2\lambda}$ it was  $\dfrac{4\lambda}{n}e^{-4\lambda}$.

Could anyone lead me further with this?

Comment: As $\Pr\{Y_1 = 0\} = e^{-\lambda}$, you may try to start with the unbiased estimator $\displaystyle \frac {1} {n} \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{1}_{Y_i = 0}$, and then apply the Rao-Blackwell + Lehmann–Scheffé theorem

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2690233/