# Finding an unbiased estimator of$ e^{−2λ}$ for Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, estimation

The random variable X has a Poisson distribution with unknown
mean λ, where 0 < λ < ∞.

Based on a single X , Is it possible to calculate an unbiased estimator of $ e^{−2λ}$ ?

I have taken an Indicator random variable as follows :-

$I_A = P(X=0)  \qquad\text{if } X=0\\
     \,\,\,\,\,\,= 0 \quad\qquad\qquad\text{if } X\neq0 $

Then $E(I_A) = e^{-2\lambda}$

However I am not sure if this is correct .IF This is not correct kindly help me out.

Thanks.

Ps: I have found a similar question , :[Finding an unbiased estimator of $e^{-2\lambda}$ for Poisson distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2689276/finding-an-unbiased-estimator-of-e-2-lambda-for-poisson-distribution)

Comment: There is only one unbiased estimator of $e^{-2 \lambda}$ from a single observation, namely $(-1)^X$, and it is not a particularly sensible estimator as it only gives the values $+1$ or $-1$  when in fact $0 \lt e^{-2 \lambda} \lt 1$ unless $\lambda=0$.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_of_an_estimator#Estimating_a_Poisson_probability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proposed estimator is not $I_A$ for any $A$. If it was, it should return $1$ when $X\in A$ and $0$ otherwise.

Moreover, it is also wrong to say that
$$\hat \theta =\left\{\begin{matrix}P(X=0)&X=0,\\0&X\neq0,\\\end{matrix}\right.$$
is an estimator for $\theta=e^{-2\lambda}$, since $P(X=0)=e^{-\lambda}=\sqrt\theta$. Your proposed estimator for $\theta$ can be anything BUT a function that depends on $\theta$ itself.